# how to get the ip of my Ubuntu instance in AWS

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2

How can I see the public IP address assigned to an EC2 instance, from within (i.e. after connecting) the EC2 instance?  I can see the public IP address that is assigned to it, simply by looking in the Management Console.

From [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html), we can get the public ip address using the following curl command.

```
$ TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"` && curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data
```

but looks like it doesn't work.

```
$ TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"` && curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    56  100    56    0     0  28000      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 56000
*   Trying 169.254.169.254:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 169.254.169.254 (169.254.169.254) port 80 (#0)
> GET /latest/meta-data HTTP/1.1
> Host: 169.254.169.254
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: AQAAAEKVNCUB3KPoodSB0SFUkkn1aSah2MRUxAVQQx_3SeVBllVoFA==
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 324
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2022 11:29:43 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Nov 2022 18:36:36 GMT
< X-Aws-Ec2-Metadata-Token-Ttl-Seconds: 21600
< Connection: close
< Server: EC2ws
< 
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
auth-identity-credentials/
block-device-mapping/
events/
hostname
iam/
identity-credentials/
instance-action
instance-id
instance-life-cycle
instance-type
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
metrics/
network/
placement/
profile
public-keys/
reservation-id
security-groups
services/
```

Any idea how to get the public ip in EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler `curl` command would be:

```
$ curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data
```

and will return the following output:

```
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
events/
hostname
identity-credentials/
instance-action
instance-id
instance-life-cycle
instance-type
ipv6
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
metrics/
network/
placement/
profile
public-hostname
public-ipv4
public-keys/
reservation-id
security-groups
services/
```

As you see here, the URL to get the "public IPv4" would be:

```
$ curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

Some other (shell script) examples:

```
localIP=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)
publicIP=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4)
inst_type=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type)
av_zone=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
```

On the other hand, to get the local IPv4 address and the IPv6 address (AWS does *not* provide an API to query the IPv6 address) with a system command, you can use:

```
$ hostname -I
```

Note that there is no way to get the public IPv4 unless you ask for it on an external server, like the "AWS server" (`http://169.254.169.254/`) or servers on Internet (as provided in the other answer).

Answer (score 0):

I generally use an external service for this. If you would like the IPv4 address for your server to be recorded in a file named `ip_v4.txt`, you can do this:

```
wget -q -nv https://api.ipify.org -O ip_v4.txt
```

If you would like the IPv6 address in a file named `ip_v6.txt`, you can do this:

```
wget -q -nv https://api64.ipify.org -O ip_v6.txt
```

Naturally, you may need to customise this to output the address in the manner that you'd like.

This gets around the issues of using Amazon's various APIs and provides something a little more universal that can work on any Linux-based server, regardless of where it is hosted.